# 'Module Not Found Issue'

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

There is an issue in my Project and stating 'Cannot find module ' after several attempts and I am trying to install and uninstall the packages simultaneously, the issue is not resolving.
**[image: Here is the code of my package.json file:-]**

```
{
      "name": "tooling-01-starting-project",
      "version": "1.0.0",
      "description": "JavaScript The Complete Guide",
      "main": "eslint.js",
      "scripts": {
        "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
        "build": "webpack"
      },
      "author": "Junaid Jawed",
      "license": "ISC",
      "devDependencies": {
        "eslint": "^7.32.0",
        "webpack": "^5.53.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.8.0",
        "webpack-dev-server": "^4.2.1"
      },
      "dependencies": {
        "grunt": "^1.4.1"
      }
```

}

**Below this is my webpack.config.js file coding:-**

```
 /* eslint-disable no-undef */
const path = require('path');

module.exports =
{
    entry:'./src/app.js',
    output:
    {
        filename:'app.js',
        path:path.resolve(__dirname,'assets','scripts')
    }

};

    const path2 = require('path');
    
    module.exports =
    {
        entry:'./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js',
        output:
        {
            filename:'webpack.js',
            path2:path2.resolve(__dirname,'webpack','bin')
        }
    
    };
```

Also above I have attached an screenshot of my error in npm command prompt:-

Can somebody tell me what is the problem of this issue? I think it doesn't found the file location where my webpack.js file is located.

Answer (score 1):

I've been stuck with that kind of issues for times in the past.

One thing that it could be, is about the project location. Here it is said that's in `E:\`, try to relocate it in `C:\Users\YourUser\Documents\MyProject` and do the following:

Run `npm i` command, and start the solution. If it doesn't work, could be an issue regarding the version of node that's installed in your computer...

Comment: hope this can be useful to anyone then :)

Answer (score 0):

To solve this just add `"type": "module"` in your   **package.json** file and you are good to go!